# Java and Python - System.console() returns null when started from subprocess

Tags: java, python, console, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to start a Java file in a subprocess in Python. The problem is that System.console() returns null in Java, though I'm redirecting the std streams.

```
server_startcmd = [
           "java", 
           "-Xmx%s" % self.java_heapmax, 
           "-Xms%s" % self.java_heapmin,
           "-jar",
           self.server_jar,
           self.java_gui,
    ]

    self.server = Popen(
          server_startcmd,
          stdout = PIPE,
          stderr = PIPE,
          stdin  = PIPE
    )

    self.outputs = [
          self.server_socket,
          self.server.stderr,
          self.server.stdout,
          sys.stdin
    ]
```

When I execute the Java command from the command line, it works fine.

I really can't figure it out. Can I simulate a console or something like that?

Comment: Can you try to write server_startcmd as a string but not a list?

Comment: Thanks but nope, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I used pty to make a pseudoterminal.

This time in ruby:

```
require 'pty'

@master_io, slave = PTY.open
read, @write_pipe = IO.pipe
pid = spawn(server_startcmd, :in=>read, :out=>slave)

read.close
slave.close

output = @master_io.gets
@write_pipe.write("something")
```

Thanks for the help though!